# NMAP module has no attribute PortScanner() Error:

Tags: python, nmap

I'am making a nmap port scanner script but I come across this error nmap has no attribute PortScanner(). this is a common problem, is there someone that actually knows how to fix this.

I tried pip uninstall nmap, pip install python-nmap but nothing sees to work. In /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ there is two folders nmap and python_nmap-0.6.4.egg-info. In the nmap folder there is a file nmap.py on it does have the class PortScanner() I tried transferring the file to the python_nmap-0.6.4.egg-info folder to see if it works but NO. and in the python_nmap-0.6.3.egg-info folder there is only text files and NO actual python modules.

Is there any other solution out there that someone knows about? I tried a lot of methods but none work.

Comment: Is your file named `nmap.py`, by chance?

Comment: @MattDMo my file name is nmScan.py. It's all good man this is a common error thats happening and I looked every where but no solution. :(